# Is $f(x,y)$ differentiable at the origin?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $f(x,y) = \dfrac {xy^3}{x^3 + y^6 }$ if $(x,y) \ne (0,0)$ and define $f(0,0)=0$

Determine if $f$ is differentiable at the origin or not.

**Attempt:**

$D_1f(0,0) = \lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \dfrac {h.0}{h^3}=0$. Similarily :

$D_2f(0,0) =0$.

By Taylors Expansion :

$f(a+v) = f(a) + T_a(v) + ||v|| E(a,v)$

$\implies f(a+hy) = f(a) + T_a(hy) + ||v|| E(a,y)$ where $y$ is a unit vector.

> Substituting $a=(0,0): f(v) = f(0) + v\circ \nabla f(0) \ + ||v||E(0;y)$

Let $||v|| \rightarrow 0.$ If $v = (h_1,h_2)$, then $v\circ \nabla f(0) = h_1 \cdot D_1f(0) +  h_2 \cdot D_2 f(0) = 0$

$\implies \dfrac {h_1h_2^3}{h_1^3+h_2^6} = \sqrt {h_1^2+h_2^2} E(0,v)$

Taking $h_1=h_2$, we get :

$\implies \dfrac {h^4}{h^3+h^6} = \sqrt 2 h E(o,v)$

But, $E(0,v) = \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \dfrac {1}{1+h^3} \ne 0$

Hence, $f$ must not be differentiable at the origin. However, my textbook says that it is differentiable at the origin.

Could somebody be able to advise on this problem.

Thank you very much for your help in this regard.

Comment: The textbook is wrong. It's not differentiable at origin, it's not even continuous there.

Comment: Thanks. That means the derivative $f ′(0,a)$ does not exist for any vector a also right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not even continuous in $(0,0)$ in fact:
$$
f(t^2,t) = \frac{t^5}{t^6+t^6} = \frac{1}{2t} \to \pm \infty 
$$
as $t\to 0$.

Comment: Thanks. That means the derivative $f~'(0,a)$ does not exist for any vector $a$ also right?

Comment: What is $f'(0,a)$ when $a$ is a vector?